# Como puedo enviar 2 variables mediante ajax no se como hacerlo e intentado de varias formas

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, ajax

Tengo problemas con mi sintaxis para enviar 2 datos atravez de mi ajax y traer los datos para mostrarlos en mi modal no se como hacerlo e visto varios ejemplos pero no puedo adaptarlo a mi codigo

```
   <div class="box" align="center">

                <div class="box-body">
                    <div class="content">
                        <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>PROVEEDOR</th>
                                <th>DESC_ENLACE</th>
                                <th>NO_FACTURA</th>
                                <th>ID_ENLACE</th>
                                <th>VALOR_PAGO</th>
                                <th>PERIODO</th>
                                <th>FECHA_FACTURA</th>
                                <th>OPCIONES</th>
                                <th>OPCIONES</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            @foreach($datos as $datos)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{$datos->proveedor}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$datos->desc_enlace}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$datos->no_factura}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$datos->id_enlace}}</td>
                                    <td>{{$datos->valor_pago}}</td>
                                    <td>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($datos->periodo)->format('d-m-Y')}}</td>
                                    <td>{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($datos->fecha_factura)->format('d-m-Y')}}</td>

                                    <td>
                                        <a  href="#" class="btn btn-primary active"  id='Datos'.{{$datos->id_enlace,$datos->periodo}}; data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Editar</a>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a  href="{{url('eliminar/'.$datos->id_enlace.'/'.$datos->periodo)}}"  class="btn btn-danger active" role="button" aria-pressed="true">Eliminar</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                            @endforeach
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
```

Este es mi ajax el cual esta en la misma pagina que mi modal y mi datatables

```
     <script>
    $(document).on("click","#Datos", function(){

        var loc = $(this).attr('datos_modal');
        var date= $(this).val();


        $.ajax({
            url:loc,
            data: date,
            method: 'GET',
            cache: true,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                alert('Bien')
            },
            error : function(xhr, status) {
                console.log(status);
                // alert('Disculpe, existió un problema'+status);
            },
        })
    })
</script>
```

Esta es mi ruta

```
  Route::GET('datos_modal/{id_enlace}/{periodo}',[
    'as'=>'datos_modal',
    'uses'=>'vista@modal'
]);
```

Este es mi controlador el cual me recibe las variables pero si no recargo la pagina me esta caendo los mismos datos y al momento de retornar los datos que estoy buscando me tira un error al momento de quererlos mostrar en mi modal

```
   public function modal($id_enlace,$periodo)
    {


        dd($id_enlace,$periodo);

        $modal = importar::select('proveedor', 'desc_enlace', 'no_factura', 'id_enlace', 'valor_pago', 'periodo', 'fecha_factura', 'fecha_ingreso')
            ->where('ID_ENLACE', $id_enlace)->where('PERIODO', $periodo)->get();

       dd($modal);

        return \View::make('formulario')->with(
            [
                'modal' => $modal
            ]
        );
    }
```

este es mi modal en el cual quiero mostrar mis datos pero no se como por que al momento de traer la variable me tira un error

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <center><h4 class="modal-title">Editar_Cliente</h4></center>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <form>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="inputEmail4">Proveedor</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" value=""id="inputEmail4">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="inputPassword4">Id_enlace</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control"  value=""  id="inputPassword4">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputAddress">Desc_enlace</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control"  value=""id="inputAddress" placeholder="1234 Main St">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputAddress2">Valor_pago</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAddress2" value=""placeholder="Apartment, studio, or floor">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="inputCity">Periodo</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control"  value=""id="inputCity">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <label for="inputCity">Fecha Factura</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control"  value=""id="inputCity">
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <center><button  type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button></center>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Para empezar, todos los enlaces para activar el modal tienen la misma id `id="myModall"` y este debe ser único, precisamente para poder "identificar" cada elemento. Desconozco Laravel y no sé si te crea automáticamente el evento click para cada enlace o lo haces por tu cuenta, pero habría que ver cómo cargas los datos en la ventana modal.

Comment: Solo tengo un enlace con ese nombre y es el de editar precisamente   el cual me activa mi ajax que tengo y ese ed myModall y el otro myModal

Comment: Lo que dice @Triby se refiere a que el enlace que recibe el ID "myModall", si bien lo tienes una vez en el codigo, al estar en un bucle saldrá las n veces que el bucle de vueltas. Así que en estricto rigo lo tendras n veces y el ID debe ser unico.

Comment: Entonces tengo que sacar el boton bucle o como tendria que hacerlo por que si saco el boton entonces ya no me leera los valores de esa fila alguna idea como puedo hacerlo

Comment: Solo tienes que asignar ID única, sería algo como `id="enlace-{{$datos->id_enlace}}"`, de esta forma, no importa que esté dentro del ciclo, en cada iteración se asigna ID de acuerdo al elemento que se está mostrando.

Comment: Creo que ya mire mi problema pero no se como podria solucionarlo por ejemplo le quite el id=myModall para ver y siempre me habre el modal con los datos entonces quiere decir que el dd que hago en mi controlador siempre me esta enviando los datos por el boton hacia el controlador y no me esta utilizando mi ajax para la consulta la ruta que utilizar mi ajax no me la esta tomando y se esta llendo ala ruta directamente

Comment: Ahi edite mi respuesta coloque mi ajax aunque estoy viendo que esta malo desde el momento que miro mi boton para que me haga referencia a mi ajax mediante un evento y no se como hacerlo

Comment: Como ya indicaron los compañeros, tener varios elementos con el mismo `id` no es correcto, aunque en algunos contextos podría funcionar, en otros es un desastre. En el escenario que describes lo será, porque estarás intentando escuchar un `id` múltiple lo cual es un lío. Si observas esto: `$(document).on("click","#Datos", function(){` estás agregando un *listener*  por el id (eso es lo que significa `#` en los selectores jQuery, por lo tanto, si tienes varios elementos con un `id="Datos"` rápidamente llega la confusión a tu código. Creo que para arrojar un poco de luz en tu problema ...

Comment: ... es mejor que asignes **una clase común**, eso sí se puede repetir las veces que quieras, y agregar un listener para esa clase. O sea, a cada elemento dinámico le asignarías : `class="unaClase"` y pondrías un listener parecido a este: **`$(document).on("click",".unaClase", function(){`** observa el cambio de `#Datos` a `.unaClase`, es fundamental en jQuery entender cómo funcionan [los selectores](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), para que no te pierdas en el código.

Comment: Podrias aplicarlo a mi codigo como respuesta es que estoy viendo que  no me esta mandando  a mi ruta igual para mas o menos irme guiando

Comment: Lo que quiero es traer los datos de mi controlador y por eso le envio los datos para identificarlos en mi consulta que esta en mi controlador nunca e trabajado con ajax ya que solo asi podria mostrar los datos que traigo en mi modal pero no se si mi sintaxis que tengo va buena o si me la pueden corregir desde mi boton y revisar mi ajax